# Elasticsearch: Can i safely delete shrunk index?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I used the Shrink API to shrink an index from 500 shards down to 100. But it seems that no new disk space was taken after the operation was complete.

Can i safely delete the original index with 500 shards? or does the new index rely on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i safely delete the original index with 500 shards? or does the new index rely on that?

Yes, deleting an index does not affect any other indices.

> But it seems that no new disk space was taken after the operation was complete.

This is expected, at least initially. The documentation for the [shrink API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-shrink-index.html#how-shrink-works) notes that usually the shrunken index is made by [hard-linking](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) the files of the original index rather than copying them. Hard-linking works pretty much just like copying except that it doesn't take up any extra space. In particular, if you have two hard links to the same underlying data then you can delete one of them without affecting the other, and this is the property that Elasticsearch is using when shrinking.